# (p ∧ q) ∧ (p ⇒ ¬q) prove contradiction?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

So I have reached dead end after this I tried doing de Morgan rule after this but and faced dead end after that.
I have tried this

```
(p ∧ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)
(p ∧ q) ∧ ¬(p ∧ q)
```

Comment: Did you try to just check for this contradiction directly (i.e. evaluate expression in all possible cases)?

Comment: @Cerberus yes i tried truth table and it is contradiction but i could not prove it with logical equivalences

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not explicitly about programming, but about math. See https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Off topic. Should be on the math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(p ∧ q) ∧ (p ⇒ ¬q) prove contradiction without truth table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377468/p-%e2%88%a7-q-%e2%88%a7-p-%e2%87%92-%c2%acq-prove-contradiction-without-truth-table)

Comment: don't post the question again. Post on [math.se] instead, or ask a moderator to move it for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact, your second expression is already in the form you need: it states that `A ∧ ¬A`, which is contradiction by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let p ∧ q = X, then

(p ∧ q) ∧ ¬(p ∧ q) can be written as X ∧ ¬ X which is contradiction by Complement Law.

Comment: Instead of blindly down voting could you enlist the reason for down vote. I agree this should be moved to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh sorry i think it was by mistake i was trying to choose it as right answer

Comment: Then, kindly undo your downvoting also.

Answer (score -1):

`(p ∧ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)`

By [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) it becomes:

`(p ∧ q) ∧ -(p ∧ q)`

Thus a contradiction: `(p ∧ q) AND NOT (p ∧ q)`

[image: Contradiction]

For example:
`p = "I went to the beach"`
`q = "I played football"`

What the logic is stating is the following:

`I went to the beach and played football, and I did not go to the beach and I did not play football`

It is a contradiction.